# Way to reference SSM in different region in serverless framwork

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-ssm

Serverless offers a function to access `SSM`.

```
${ssm:/parameter-path}
```

However, It seems only to allow access to `SSM`(parameter) in the same region.

Is there way to reference `SSM` in a different region?

Sometimes there are parameters globally used.

For those, I want to create them in a single region then share them accross multi-region.

Otherwise, I should redefine the same parameters in every region.

Comment: Documentation (https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/) says you can add the region in brackets after SSM, but that doesn't work for me.  I'm wondering if there's a version requirement or something?

Answer (score 0):

The serverless documentation says that you add the region in brackets after ssm in the variable name: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

e.g. `ssm(eu-west-1)`

However, that didn't work for me.  Adding it with a dot `.` between the ssm and the region e.g. `ssm.eu-west-1` did work and you can see it referenced in the pull request that created it.

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/7625

This was in serverless 1.77.x, so I'm providing both answers in case the bracket notation is a serverless 2 thing.